# Using protobuf-net, what is the correct way to serialize a derived type that implements an interface?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, enyim

I realize that there are similar questions here, but none that asks this quite as straightforwardly as what I need, probably because of my lack of protobuf experience. I am transcoding for enyim's caching client, and having trouble figuring out how to make a class that is both derived and implementing an interface de/serialize correctly.

For a sample like this

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public interface ISomeRules
{
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, ISomeRules
{
}

public class ThirdClass
{
    ISomeRules ruleUser;
}
```

I want to do something like this, because I generally use attributes everywhere

```
[ProtoContract
,ProtoInclude(101,typeof(DerivedClass))
]
public class BaseClass
{
}

[ProtoContract
,ProtoInclude(102,typeof(DerivedClass))
]
public interface ISomeRules
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, ISomeRules
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ThirdClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    ISomeRules ruleUser;
}
```

but it fails caching silently. If as some have suggested I remove the `ProtoContract` attribute from `ISomeRules`, the deserialization fails.

Is this doable using protobuf-net? What is the right way to do this? Should I be using the TypeModel (which I do not master, but which simple tests indicate has the same problem) instead? Or a combination of TypeModel and attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface support in protobuf-net is intended for limited scenarios, you you are basically working to an interface-based model, in particular for nested members. For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IBar Bar {get;set;}
}
```

In the above, we want to be able to serialize the `Bar`, but we might not know a lot about it. In fact, if `Foo` guarantees to return a non-null value from `Bar`, protobuf-net doesn't even need to know anything about concrete types etc - it can just go ahead and populate the object it is given.

In your example, the root object is unquestionably `BaseClass`. I would suggest that `ISomeRules` is anciliary, and does not need to be mentioned *at all* in the model. However, if you *want* to populate members that are **only** exposed via `ISomeRules`, then you might try (untested):

```
[ProtoMember(n)]
private ISomeRules Rules { get { return this; } }
```

This then exposes the `ISomeRules` information, but spoofing it as a sub-object. It is, at the minimum, worth a try; p

Comment: Thanks, will put that on the list of possible solutions. If in my graph I am serializing, say, a `DerivedClass` object in one place, and that same object as an `ISomeRules` somewhere else, if I use `AsReference` without the model mention for ISomeRules it barfs on deserialization. If I *don't* use AsReference, will that object serialize twice?

Comment: @downwitch.... *yeah*... `AsReference` doesn't (at the moment) play nicely with inheritance and interfaces. I need to fix that.

Comment: ok, so just to make sure I understand that: `AsReference` prevents double serialization, but requires model declaration?

Comment: @downwitch it requires *simple models*, until I can invest some time for more complex scenarios

Comment: OK, thanks, just wanted to make sure I understood the rules. I do have a complex model (much more so than this), so it may be that I can work around this problem by shifting to some other root type.

Comment: @downwitch the simplest guidance I can give would be "avoid inheritance on objects that are also using AsReference". Not really much to do with the root type.